# What is the best professional way to detect the status of several ajax requests in Angular8?

Tags: angular, ajax, rxjs, httpclient

The one completed variable is consisted of 6 parts like the following

```
selectedCandidateData: Candidate = {
    candidateBasic: null,
    experienceList: null,
    educationList: null,
    certificationList: null,
    candidateAbout: null,
};
```

each parts will get by each ajax calling like the following

```
// get the profile data of selected candidate
this.candidateService.getBasic(candidatePersonalInfo.id).subscribe(
    (candidateBasic) => {
        this.selectedCandidateData.candidateBasic = candidateBasic;
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);

this.candidateService.getExperience(candidatePersonalInfo.id).subscribe(
    (experienceList) => {
        this.selectedCandidateData.experienceList = experienceList;
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);

this.candidateService.getEducation(candidatePersonalInfo.id).subscribe(
    (educationList) => {
        this.selectedCandidateData.educationList = educationList;
    },
    (error) => {
    console.log(error);
    }
);

this.candidateService.getCertification(candidatePersonalInfo.id).subscribe(
    (certificationList) => {
        this.selectedCandidateData.certificationList = certificationList;
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);

this.candidateService.getAbout(candidatePersonalInfo.id).subscribe(
    (candidateAbout) => {
        this.selectedCandidateData.candidateAbout = candidateAbout;
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```

as you see at the above, **selectedCandidateData** will be made after 6 ajax calling. I made the following function to detect the all 6 ajax request success.

```
selectedCandidateDataLoaded() {
    return (
        this.selectedCandidateData.candidateBasic !== null &&
        this.selectedCandidateData.experienceList !== null &&
        this.selectedCandidateData.educationList !== null &&
        this.selectedCandidateData.certificationList !== null &&
        this.selectedCandidateData.candidateAbout !== null
    );
}
```

so at the template, for rendering I used like the following code

```
<app-candidate-profile *ngIf="selectedCandidateDataLoaded()" [candidate]="selectedCandidateData"></app-candidate-profile>
```

as I see, my current solution is very bad and doesn't look very professional.
for improving my code, I reviewed about Angular8 and I find **Rxjs**.
it seems that **Rxjs** can help me to make my code simple and looks very professional.

**How can I make this simple and professional?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `forkJoin` operator for your use case in two flavors :

1 - In your component constructor or ngOnInit do the following :

```
forkJoin(
  {
    candidateBasic: this.candidateService.getBasic(candidatePersonalInfo.id),
    experienceList: this.candidateService.getExperience(candidatePersonalInfo.id), 
    educationList: this.candidateService.getEducation(candidatePersonalInfo.id),
    certificationList: this.candidateService.getCertification(candidatePersonalInfo.id),
    candidateAbout : this.candidateService.getAbout(candidatePersonalInfo.id)
  }
)
.subscribe(e => this.selectedCandidateData = e)
```

And in your template use `selectedCandidateData` variable instead of  `selectedCandidateDataLoaded()`

Or

2 - write directly the `forkJoin` inside `selectedCandidateDataLoaded()` method and don’t subscribe.

```js
selectedCandidateDataLoaded() : Observable<Candidate> {
   return forkJoin({...});
}
```

In your template use async pipe like :

```js
*ngIf="selectedCandidateDataLoaded() | async"
```

Comment: Hello @bubbles, Thanks for your comment. What can I do in ReactJS at the case like this?

Comment: Sorry i’ve never used ReactJs